# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Usuarios could not be converted to string in

Tags: php

Tengo un registro de usuarios, el problema es que no me deja regisrarme, me da el error del titulo.
Esta es la funcion llama registro_usuario();

```
 // REGISTRO DE USUARIO
public function registro_usuario($nombre,$email,$usuario,$pasword,$nacimiento,$genero){

    $resp=[];
    try{
        //VERIFICAR SI EXISTE EL USUARIO
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM kv_users WHERE email = ?";
        $smt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $smt->execute(array($email));
        $resp = $smt->fetch();


        //SI NO EXISTE EMAIL MATAMOS LA OPERACIÓN
        if($resp){
            echo "<script>window.location = 'registro.php?e=2';</script>";
            die();
        }

        //HASH DE CONTRASEÑA
        $pasword = password_hash($pasword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        //var_dump($password);


        $insert="INSERT INTO kv_users(nombre, email, usuario, nacimiento, genero) VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try{
            $smt_insert=$this->pdo->prepare($insert);
            $smt_insert->execute(array(
                $nombre, $email, $usuario, $pasword, $nacimiento, $genero
            ));
        }catch(Eception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

       echo "<script> window.location = 'login.php?msj=registrado';</script>";

    }catch (Eception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $resp;        
}
```

El error me lo esta marcando en la linea 74, la cual es donde se encuentran las variables dentro del array()
(Lineas: 73,74,75)

```
$smt_insert->execute(array(
          $nombre, $email, $usuario, $pasword, $nacimiento, $genero
 ));
```

Comment: Seguramente algun de las variables $nombre, $usuario, $nacimiento o $genero no es un string, de ahí que dé el error. Comprueba mediante un var_dump() el valor de dichos campos.

Comment: Creo que te sobra una '?' en la query de inserción, son 5 campos y le pasas 6 valores a rellenar con un array de 5 elementos

Comment: @Carmen ya agregue el campo password en el insert, para que sean 6 los campos y 6 los ?, pero el problema continua

Comment: Probablemente alguna de las variables produce un error que impide que la sentencia para la inserción se forme correctamente. Puedes probar imprimiendo la sentencia completa en php para ver que es correcta y funcional, y en ese caso ya aplicas el reemplazo de variables.